# Filter by OwnerId is not working

Tags: apex, soql

I'm stucked with an issue. What is wanted is to filter search by Subject,Status,ActivityDate.It is filtering , now i want to filter by one more field "OwnerId" here.How do i go about this ? Any suggestions and modifications will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
    public void findTasks(){
           String qStr2 = 'Select count() from Task where Subject like  \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR Status like \'%'+searchText+'%\'';
           CountTotalRecords = Database.countQuery(qStr2);
           queryTasks();
        }

  public void  queryTasks(){

    String qStr2= searchText;
    String strnormal = '';
    try{
         mydate = date.parse(qStr2);
    }catch(Exception e)
    { }

    String strDate = '';
    if(mydate != null) {
     // strnormal = String.valueOf(mydate );
      String[] qstr3 = String.valueOf(mydate).split(' ',2);  
      strDate = ' ActivityDate =  '+ qstr3[0] + ' ';
    }else{

       strDate  =  'Subject like \'%'+searchText +'%\' OR Status like \'%' +searchText+ '%\' Order By '  + sortField;
    }
    String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '  + strDate   ;
     System.debug(qStr ); 
     sApplySOQL = qStr;
     tasks = Database.query(sApplySOQL );
    //tasks.sort();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the set of User Id values you want to filter by in a collection called e.g. `ownerIds` you can bind that directly into the dynamic SOQL by name (because this is a [simple bind variable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)):

```
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();

// Code that adds User IDs to the ownerIds set

if (logical condition that you want to filter by owner) {
    qStr + ' and OwnerId in :ownerIds';
}
```

(You can use the same binding technique for the other two filtering values which typically results in cleaner code and avoids the [SOQL injection risk](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm).)

Comment: Quite near . What should be the condition to filter by owner?

Comment: @james The "in" means match any of the Owner IDs in the set. Whether this should be an "and" or an "or" is up to you on how you want the filtering to work. "And" would be what I would probably expect as a user.

Comment: I'm little confused here.I understood use of "in", any pointing on what can be the If condition ?

Comment: @james If you always want to to the owner filtering then you can just get rid of the if. If you want to have a checkbox on the page e.g. "Filter by Owners" then you can just have its value in the if. Its up to you.